# Cant visit links without adding a question mark to the URL

Tags: javascript, php, html, .htaccess

Every time when I click on an URL I get a 404. That's because the page can't be found. But when I add a question mark right after the .domain the page is found. This was not the problem when I had the website hosted in a subdomain folder. A question mark is required to visit a page and I don't want to have the question mark.

Please see the url: http://www.ankehesselmann.nl/

I'm using StaceyApp

This is my .htaccess

```html
RewriteEngine on

# Some hosts require a rewritebase rule, if so, uncomment the RewriteBase line below. If you are running from a subdirectory, your rewritebase should match the name of the path to where stacey is stored.
ie. if in a folder named 'stacey', RewriteBase /stacey
RewriteBase /stacey

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

# Rewrite any calls to *.html, *.json, *.xml, *.atom, *.rss, *.rdf or *.txt if a folder matching * exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/$1.$2 !-f
RewriteRule (.+)\.(html|json|xml|atom|rss|rdf|txt)$ $1/ [L]

#Add a trailing slash to directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ([^/]+)$ $1/ [L]

# Rewrite any calls to /* or /app to the index.php file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /app/$
RewriteRule ^app/ index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?$1 [L]

# Rewrite any file calls to the public directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ public/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing the RewriteBase is set to the wrong folder in your .htaccess
Though I cannot explain why it works with the question mark as you said, I would try setting the RewriteBase correctly.

You have to put the sub-folder (path from domain name until your index-file) if you have any. E.g.:

Website located at: example.com/folder1/sub/

```
RewriteBase /folder1/sub/
```

If your website doesn't have a sub-folder:

```
RewriteBase /
```

You may try removing the line if you haven't got a sub-folder, but it should not make any problems if set to / (slash).